# "a too strong signal" Or "too strong of a signal"

Tags: grammar

> The object is emitting too strong of a signal that it's unreasonable to consider it to be a mere chunk of scrap metal.
>
> The object is emitting a too strong signal that it's unreasonable to consider it to be a mere chunk of scrap metal.

Actually the first one is the original sentence, but that kind of structure is rather unfamiliar to me. Could you let me know what's the difference or what's the correct usage here?

Comment: _Too strong that_ doesn't make sense to me. Either _too strong a signal for it to be reasonable to consider..._ or _such a strong signal that it's unreasonable..._

Comment: Your second version is "syntactically valid", but extremely "non-idiomatic" (native speakers simply wouldn't say it, because it's "awkward"). Another issue is that some (esp. American) native speakers would normally include ***of*** in the noun phrase *too strong **of** a signal*, whereas most of us would just use ***too strong a signal***. And the structure of the entire utterance becomes incorrect after the word ***signal*** anyway.

Comment: I hate 'too [adjective] **of a**  [something]' very much.